# how to redirect the URL in magento?

Tags: magento, redirect

how to redirect the URL in Magento if i click on category or subcategory it should show page which i have created because of responsive design i'm doing this

I've created the URL for pages in such a way that the both category and subcategory URL is equal to page URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this all you have to do is to add URL rewrite. For example if you category id is 10 and cms page link is "cmspage.html", then in magento backend admin go to

```
catalog->URLrewrite Management and search for id 10 in ID path column copy the "Target Path" field data now write a custom url rewrite for this "Target Path"

go to Catalog->URL rewrite Management, Click Add URL rewrite button.  choose “Custom” from “Create URL Rewrite” drop-down list. add the details like belwo

Request Path — It must be the Target path which  copied before (catalog/category/view/id/10) in above.

Target Path — It should be the CMS page URL
```

That's it you will have linked category with custom cms page